# How to increment rank for each break in consecutive sequence

Tags: r, rank

I have a variable in my dataframe, yearweek, that represents just that, the week and the year (e.g. 201501 = week 1 of year 2015). I want to rank this variable but increment the rank when n+1 does not immediately follow n. Ultimately what I want the rank to look like is as follows:

```
yearweek     rank
201501       1
201502       1
201503       1
201507       2
201510       3
201511       3
201512       3
201520       4
```

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

We take the difference of adjacent elements, check if that is not equal to 1, and get the cumulative sum of the logical vector.

```
df1$rank <- cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(df1$yearweek)!=1))
df1
#  yearweek rank
#1   201501    1
#2   201502    1
#3   201503    1
#4   201507    2
#5   201510    3
#6   201511    3
#7   201512    3
#8   201520    4
```